# Bash script , loop doesn't refresh txt.file

Tags: bash

I want to write a bash script that will create a file `time.txt` in the home directory of the logged in user, put time in it and update it every *n* seconds until the script is stopped.

So far I have:

```
#! /bin/bash

do
echo "Current time" > time.txt
chmod +rwx "time.txt"

time=$(date + "%T")
echo "$time" >> time.txt

sleep 2;

watch -n 1 head -n2 time.txt.

done
```

The script isn't refreshing. It gives the right date but only once. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script isn't syntactically valid. There's no `while` or `for` loop to go along with the `do`-`done` block. Adding a loop will

```
while true; do
    date +%T >> time.txt
    sleep 2
done
```

You'll want to get rid of the `watch` call inside the loop. `watch` is itself a neverending loop that will prevent successive iterations from running.

Comment: Or, `watch` allows you to [snoop on another tty line](http://man.freebsd.org/watch). Or it might not exist at all. :)  I think it's worth mentioning that since it's not part of bash, so it's not something that can be expected to work portably.

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
while :; do
    # I'm assuming you want to see the date displayed on the terminal too.
    echo -e "Current time.\n$(date +%T)" | tee time.txt | sed '/Current time/d'
    sleep 2
done
```

The `:` is a shorthand of the `true` command.